# jquery the parent dialog textbox is locked after open dialog again

Tags: jquery-ui

I open modal dialog twice,
the textbox is locked in the first dialog(parent dialog) after the second dialog closed
Why? How to resolve the problem?  I am new user,so I can't post the image
Any answer will be appreciated, thank you

Html:

```
<XMP>
<input id="btnDlg" type="button" value="open dialog" />
<div id="dlg1"><%=Html.TextBox("txtName","can not edit") %><input id="btnShowDlg" type="button" value="dialog again" /></div>
<div id="dlg2"><div>the second dialog</div><%=Html.TextBox("txtName2") %></div>
</XMP>
```

jquery:

```
$("#dlg1").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 350,
                width: 300,
                title: "The first dialog!",
                bgiframe: true,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'OK': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            })

            $("#dlg2").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 300,
                title: "This is the second dialog!",
                bgiframe: true,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'OK': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            })            
            $("#btnDlg").click(function() {
                $("#dlg1").dialog("open");
            })

            $("#btnShowDlg").click(function() {
                $("#dlg2").dialog("open");
            })
```

Comment: Does not any body encounter this problem.

Comment: Yes, second opening of that dialog or other dialogs lock the screen

Answer (score 1):

```
buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    //validate
                    if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                        Page_ClientValidate(newValGroup);
                    }
                    if (Page_IsValid) {
                        gettHTML(divID, PriceID);
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function (ev, ui) {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
            }

        });
        $("#" + divID).dialog('open');
        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes divid can you try Making Modal : false. it will work..

let me know..

Thanks